# AWS DynamoDB performance increase with indexes

Tags: performance, amazon-web-services, indexing, amazon-dynamodb, latency

Is there a benefit of adding a **deliberately sparse** Local Secondary Index (LSI) to a table in order to speed up the query by table's **HASH** key (by reducing only the amount of items to be examined)?

Example:

```
Table
  - processId (HASH)
  - threadId (RANGE)
  - <other fields>
  - active
```

Now let's say there are 1.000.000 processes, each having 1-20 threads, so we have about 10.000.000 items in this table. Only about 1.000 processes are active at a time, and those that are not active are *missing* the `active` field completely (therefore the index that would include `active` field would hold about 1.000 items only). Active state is per process, not per thread, so we can't have some active and some inactive threads in a single process.

The goal is to fetch all items for a given `processId`, while we don't care about inactive processes (we can simply return an empty list of threads for them).

Now the **first** option is to query this table by `processId` only.

The **second** option is to create this index:

```
LSI
  - processId (HASH)
  - active (RANGE)
```

and then also query it by `processId`.

Question: is there any benefit in creating such an index? I would assume that there is none, since looking up by hash should yield the same performance no matter how many records need to be examined. Note that I'm disregarding the fact that first option might return an inactive process as well (that I'll simply discard). I'm only interested in the latency of lookup by **HASH**, in the table with **10M** items vs. index with **1K** items.

Comment: What does your query look like? I think that's going to determine the answer. Is it just a select by processId?

Comment: Yes, just get all items by processId

Comment: I think it would only help you if you didn't want to get all the `<other fields>` in your returned record set.

Comment: OK, but if I wanted those, I could easily include them in the index as well.